# Convert inconsistent varchar date to sybase datetime

Tags: sql, ms-access, sybase

We are currently migrating database from Access to Sybase. We have a table in Access DB which has around 200K records. In the table, there are six date columns which have random values like

- mmddyyyy
- ddmmyyyy
- mdyy
- mmddyy
- abc
- xyz etc....

What is the best approach to migrate it to datetime column in sybase db.

Comment: It is impossible to resolve between the first two formats.  You need a better data source.

Comment: I agree with you. We fixed whatever we could. Rest, we are taking the issue to our product owner. Hope he points us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Many of them you can catch with this expression:

```
TrueDate = DateValue(Format(StrDate, "!@@/@@/@@@@"))
```

Of course, it can't decide between mmddyy[yy] and ddmmyy[yy] if dd is 12 or less.

mdyy values must be applied a leading zero: 0mdyy